# Matrix division with defined Array

Tags: matlab

i am trying to divide each element of Matrix "A" with each element of "B". 
I want to make a new matrix of 4 "C"

```
A=[5    6   9    1; 3    8     9   5; 5    4    2    0;7    8    2    1]
B=[-0.1125,-0.0847,-0.0569,-0.0292]
C =   A ./ B
```

but i am getting error of

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
>   same.

how i fix that issue?

Comment: seems to be a task for `bsxfun`, can you give an example input (maybe something else than zeros) and the expected output?

Comment: Matlab doesn't automatically broadcast, you need to use `bsxfun` for this: `bsxfun(@rdivide, B, A)`

Comment: Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
C = A./repmat(B,size(A,1),1);
```

Use @SHAI's answer as it is faster. Here are some stats

```
n = 100;
k = 100;
A = randi(1000,n,n);
B = randi(1000,1,n);
#mine method
tic;
for i = 1:k
    C = A./repmat(B,size(A,1),1);
end
mine = toc

mine =

    1.2330 seconds

#Shai's method
tic;
for i =1:k
    C = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, B );
end
shai = toc

shai =

    0.1085 seconds
```

I can give you a more general answer if you would give me general dimensions

Comment: @Shai you are right and I have added some stats to support your statement

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of operations it is best using [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun)

```
C = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, B );
```